# Regular Expression in R (removing spacing and punctuation characters)

Tags: r, regex

Suppose I have the following text:

```
text = c("Initial [kHz]","Initial Value [dB]",
         "Min Accept X [kHz]","Min Accept [dB]",
         "Cut-Off Frequency [kHz]",
         "Min Bandwidth Limit [kHz]","y min [dB]",
         "Max Bandwidth Limit [kHz]","y max [dB]",
         "Iter: 1 [kHz]","Iter: 1","Value: 55 [dB]",
         "Iter: 2 [kHz]","Iter: 2","Value: 59 [dB]")
```

But what I want is (which removed the spacing and the punctuation characters:

```
text = c("InitialkHz","InitialValuedB",
         "MinAcceptXkHz","MinAcceptdB",
         "CutOffFrequencykHz",
         "MinBandwidthLimitkHz","ymindB",
         "MaxBandwidthLimitkHz","ymaxdB]",
         "Iter1kHz","Iter1","Value55dB",
         "Iter2kHz","Iter2","Value59dB")
```

Can anyone help me? Please...

Comment: `gsub("\\W","",text)`

Comment: what is `\\W` in regex? I thought it was only whitespace, but it seems to do the trick here perfectly

Comment: Ыee [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to keep only alpha numeric values like this:

```
gsub('[^[:alnum:]]', '', text)
```

Comment: Hi @RAB, may I know why after I execute the command you suggested, it shows

Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

? Thank You.

Comment: really? Is your character vector named `text`? I literally ran your first line of script, then this line and it works for me

Comment: I am sorry, my mistake. The command you suggested is worked! But it only works for the data type of Character right? What if the data type is Factor? Really appreciate it Rab, thank you very much!

Comment: No worries! feel free to mark as the solution (tick under the voting buttons) to aid future readers. And factors you can just convert to character first (but test it, it might work with factors)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gsub` to remove all the punctuations and spaces from `text`.

```
gsub("[[:punct:]]| ", "", text)

# [1] "InitialkHz"           "InitialValuedB"       "MinAcceptXkHz"       
# [4] "MinAcceptdB"          "CutOffFrequencykHz"   "MinBandwidthLimitkHz"
# [7] "ymindB"               "MaxBandwidthLimitkHz" "ymaxdB"              
#[10] "Iter1kHz"             "Iter1"                "Value55dB"           
#[13] "Iter2kHz"             "Iter2"                "Value59dB"
```